# Google Forms responses create new row in spreadsheet, offsetting my query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a template form and a template spreadsheet. They are un-linked by default. I have a script that copies them both, sends them to a new clients folder in the drive and links them based on the clients name. The idea is for the client to login to a website account and make submissions to the form.

I used ***=QUERY('Form Responses'!B2:H,"select *")***, inside the spreadsheet to collect the data from Sheet #1 (responses) to Sheet #2. I had to make a script that auto changes the name of Sheet #1 to stay static. However I am running into a few problems.

When the Responses generate they push Row 2 down and thereby my query adjusts to B3. Now I either need to get around that by somehow setting the formula in a script, so it doesn't adjust or I need a script that will make an auto post/response to the form with "0" as the value and simply set the formula to B3. Either way is fine for me, because it doesn't affect the calculations if the response that gets stored in B2 is "0", but I need it automatic.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe the INDIRECT-function could make the spreadsheet more static?
Something like =INDIRECT("QUERY('Form Responses'!B2:H,'select ')") I don't know if it works though...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your formula to

```sql
=QUERY('Form Responses'!$B$2:H,"select ")
```

The `$` change makes the cell in the formula absolute instead of relative and should stop the changing of the cell in the formula.

Comment: I tried that, but that wasn't the issue. I actually used B:H to get rid of the row problem. So now it is almost there. It does everything fine, but when the sheet and the form gets copied and then linked, the query formula needs to be manually entered again. It won't pull the data on its own. Any ideas??

Comment: if your just trying to copy data to another spreadsheet, why not use the ImportRange function and import the B:H range onto your Sheet 2?

Comment: I know what you mean and it works perfectly fine, but there is one problem. The copying happens in a script, and it doesn't matter if I use ImportRange, or Query after the copying took place it will NOT display the data in the second sheet. I have to manually go in, select the cell with the formula and press ENTER. I want to automate that process

Answer (score 0):

The "usual procedure" is to submit the first response and then add the formula but in a "template scenario" this could not be convenient. An alternative is to use a formula to join the column header and the formula of the second row. I.E. Add the following formula to the cell on the first row:

```
={"Column Header";QUERY('Form Responses'!B2:H,"select B")}
```